# Seaborn Catplot - Mapping yticklabels to complete 7 point Likert scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to display the results of a likert scale survey in a catplot.

Therefore i map the values to their string representation using a list like this:

```
likert_li = ['',
             'Strongly Disagree', 
             'Disagree',
             'More or less disagree',
             'Undecided',
             'More or less agree',
             'Agree',
             'Strongly agree']
```

The plot looks like this:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="T", y=col[3], hue="Group", data=df_chat,
                kind="bar", palette="muted")
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("")
g.set_xlabels("Test")
# g.set_yticklabels(likert_li)
```

using `g.set_yticklabels(likert_li)` **turns this:**
[image]

**into this:**

[image]

As you can see the last entry 'Strongly agree' is not displayed.

**Question:** How can i display the whole Likert scale, respectively all values that are passed to `set_yticklabels()` ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have set `height` to `6`. With numbers from 0 to 6 that makes 7 labels, but in `likert_li` you define 8 labels. I don't know seaborn, but I would maybe start from checking that you actually have enough yticks to display all your labels.

Comment: Sorry, that is an unfortunate coincidence. `height` refers to the actual height of the plot, not the yticks to display! I'll remove it from this example, thank you.

Comment: Ok, but the rest of my comment still holds: you apparently don't have enough ticks to display all your labels. Check for instance the output of `plt.gca().get_yticks()`.

Comment: This returns `array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])`

Comment: This is a strange way to plot Likert results, which are normally shown as a count or a percentage for each of the qualitative outcomes. Maybe you want to check out [diverging stacked bar graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142358/create-a-diverging-stacked-bar-chart-in-matplotlib) , or [percent stacked bar graphs](https://python-graph-gallery.com/13-percent-stacked-barplot/) as more intuitive ways to display your results.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the [docs of matplotlib.pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html)

Using `plt.yticks(np.arange(len(likert_li)), likert_li)` maps all strings of the list `likert_li` as labels for the values of `np.arange(len(likert_li))`.