# Errorbar plot for Likert scale confidence values

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, errorbar

I have the following dataset, for 36 fragments in total (36 rows × 3 columns):

```
    Fragment    lower   upper
0   1           1       5
1   2           2       5
2   3           3       5
3   4           2       5
4   5           1       5
5   6           1       5
```

I've calculated these lower and upper bounds from this dataset (966 rows × 2 columns):

```
    Fragment    Confidence Value
0   33         4
1   26         4
2   23         3
3   16         2
4   36         3
```

which contains multiple instance of a fragment and an associated Confidence value.

The confidence values are data from a Likert scale, i.e. 1-5. I want to create an **error bar plot**, for example like this:

[image: errorbarplot]

So on the y-axis to have each fragment 1-36 and on the x-axis to show the range/std/mean (?) of the confidence values for each fragment.

I've tried this, but it's not exactly what I want, I think using the lower and upper bounds isn't the best idea, maybe I need std/range...

```
#confpd is the second dataset from above
meanconfs = confpd.groupby('Fragment', as_index=False)['Confidence Value'].mean()
minconfs = confpd.groupby(Fragment', as_index=False)['Confidence Value'].min()
maxconfs = confpd.groupby('Fragment', as_index=False)['Confidence Value'].max()

data_dict = {}
data_dict['Fragment'] = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18', 
                        '19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','39','31','32','33','34','35','36']
data_dict['lower'] = minconfs['Confidence Value']
data_dict['upper'] = maxconfs['Confidence Value']
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

##dataset is the first dataset I show above

for lower,upper,y in zip(dataset['lower'],dataset['upper'],range(len(dataset))):
    plt.plot((lower,upper),(y,y),'ro-',color='orange')
plt.yticks(range(len(dataset)),list(dataset['Fragment']))
```

The result of this code is this, which is not what I want.

[image: wrongplot]

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Imho, your question lacks clarity. What do you want to define as your error bar? As soon as you have answered this question, the plotting is easy by giving this error bar array to the [parameter `xerr`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/statistics/errorbar_features.html). But we cannot tell you what your error bar values are.

Comment: I think the most logical error bar would be standard deviation..

Comment: Maybe. Interquartile ranges or confidence intervals might be better. We don't know your data. The plotting, as I said, is not the problem here. Maybe you try to find the best answer for this statistical question over at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Ok, I will explore some more and try different stuff out to see what is best..Thanks for your advice

Comment: Stacked diverging horizontal bar charts are quite common to represent Likert scale results. [See here for instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384812/8881141) Again, the best representation depends on your data.